# Converting character to time in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have a list of time as shown below:

```
"0:30:00"  "1:00:00"  "1:30:00"  "10:00:00" "10:30:00" "11:00:00" "11:30:00" "12:00:00" "12:30:00" "13:00:00" "13:30:00" "14:00:00" "14:30:00"
```

When I used the as.Date function to convert these into date objects in R using the following code:

```
time1<-as.Date(time,format='%H:%M:%S')
```

It gave me the following output:

```
"2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09" "2016-05-09"
```

Why is that the case? Is there something wrong with my code or the original time format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `times` from `chron` to convert to time

```
library(chron)
times(v1)
#[1] 00:30:00
chron(times(v1))
#[1] (01/01/70 00:30:00)
```

Or use `strptime` to convert to date time objects

```
r1 <- strptime(v1, format = "%H:%M:%S")
r1
#[1] "2016-05-10 00:30:00 IST"
```

In addition to `strptime`, `POSIXct` is also possible

```
r2 <- as.POSIXct(v1, format = "%H:%M:%S")
r2
#[1] "2016-05-10 00:30:00 IST"
```

The difference between `strptime` and `POSIXct` is that the former has `POSIXlt` class whereas the latter have only `POSIXct`.  Also, if we look at the structure of both, the `strptime` is stored as a `list`

```
is.list(r1)
#[1] TRUE
is.list(r2)
#[1] FALSE
lapply(r1, I)
r1$min
#[1] 30
```

Another option is `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
hms(v1)
#[1] "30M 0S"
```

This also have the date i.e. current date.

The `as.Date` only converts to 'Date'.  It doesn't show any time.

#### data

```
v1 <- "0:30:00"
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. I tried Chron and it works perfectly. I have a dataset with many columns, of which Time is one of them. I would like to convert this column to Chron object and then sort the dataset by Time. Is this possible?

Comment: @A1122  I think after you create the column with `chron`, use `order` i.e. `df1$Time <-  chron(times(df1$yourcolumn)); df1[order(df1$Time),]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `as.POSIXct`

```
x <- c("0:30:00",  "1:00:00",  "1:30:00",  "10:00:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00" ,"11:30:00", "12:00:00", "12:30:00", "13:00:00", "13:30:00", "14:00:00", "14:30:00")

as.POSIXct(x,format="%H:%M:%S")

#[1] "2016-05-10 00:30:00 IST" "2016-05-10 01:00:00 IST" "2016-05-10 01:30:00 IST" "2016-05-10 10:00:00 IST"
#[5] "2016-05-10 10:30:00 IST" "2016-05-10 11:00:00 IST" "2016-05-10 11:30:00 IST" "2016-05-10 12:00:00 IST"
#[9] "2016-05-10 12:30:00 IST" "2016-05-10 13:00:00 IST" "2016-05-10 13:30:00 IST" "2016-05-10 14:00:00 IST"
#[13] "2016-05-10 14:30:00 IST"
```

Comment: well, your edit time suggests that your `POSIXct` answer was added after my answer was posted.